# PyVista download of examples raises error

Tags: python, pyvista

I recently discovered PyVista (which looks awesome) and wanted to go through some of the examples. However, I get an error when running `examples.download_` functions. For example, the lines

```
import pyvista as pv
from pyvista import examples

vol = examples.download_brain()
```

gives the following error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_24180/817299612.py in <module>
      2 from pyvista import examples
      3 
----> 4 vol = examples.download_brain()

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyvista\examples\downloads.py in download_brain(load)
   1912 
   1913     """
-> 1914     return _download_and_read('brain.vtk', load=load)
   1915 
   1916 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyvista\examples\downloads.py in _download_and_read(filename, texture, file_format, load, progress_bar)
    262         raise ValueError('Cannot download and read an archive file')
    263 
--> 264     saved_file = download_file(filename, progress_bar=progress_bar)
    265     if not load:
    266         return saved_file

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyvista\examples\downloads.py in download_file(filename, progress_bar)
    171     """
    172     try:  # should the file already exist within fetcher's registry
--> 173         return _download_file(filename, progress_bar)
    174     except ValueError:  # otherwise simply add the file to the registry
    175         FETCHER.registry[filename] = None

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyvista\examples\downloads.py in _download_file(filename, progress_bar)
    183         processor=Unzip() if filename.endswith('.zip') else None,
    184         downloader=_file_copier if _FILE_CACHE else None,
--> 185         progressbar=progress_bar,
    186     )
    187 

TypeError: fetch() got an unexpected keyword argument 'progressbar'
```

Other example downloads give similar errors. I run python 3.7.15 and PyVista 0.37.0.

**EDIT:** Output from pv.Report():

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Date: Mon Dec 05 08:52:47 2022 W. Europe Standard Time

                OS : Windows
            CPU(s) : 8
           Machine : AMD64
      Architecture : 64bit
               RAM : 15.7 GiB
       Environment : IPython
        GPU Vendor : Intel
      GPU Renderer : Intel(R) UHD Graphics 620
       GPU Version : 4.5.0 - Build 26.20.100.6999

  Python 3.7.15 (default, Nov 24 2022, 18:44:54) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]

           pyvista : 0.37.0
               vtk : 9.0.3
             numpy : 1.19.2
           imageio : 2.19.3
            scooby : 0.7.0
             pooch : v1.4.0
        matplotlib : 3.5.2
             PyQt5 : 5.9.2
           IPython : 7.31.1
          colorcet : 3.0.1
             scipy : 1.5.2
              tqdm : 4.64.1
        jupyterlab : 3.5.0

  Intel(R) oneAPI Math Kernel Library Version 2021.4-Product Build 20210904
  for Intel(R) 64 architecture applications
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue on linux, but with the same package versions (neither with pip nor with conda). How did you install the environment? And what is your version fo `pooch`? Currently on PyPI there's only 1.6.0 and it has the same wheel for all platforms. Most likely you have an older version of pooch from somewhere, which doesn't support `progressbar` yet in that method. [Edit]ing your question to add the output of `pv.Report()` would help pinpoint this.

Comment: Hi @AndrasDeak--СлаваУкраїні, thank you for your comment! I have `pooch` version 1.4.0  and updated the question with the output of `pv.Report()`.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Can you try updating `pooch`? That's probably the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `progressbar` kwarg that PyVista passes on to `fetch()` was implemented [in this `pooch` pull request](https://github.com/fatiando/pooch/pull/277), released in [version 1.6.0](https://github.com/fatiando/pooch/releases/tag/v1.6.0) at the end of January 2022. Updating your `pooch` version will fix this issue.

In the meantime I'll raise the issue of changing this on the PyVista side to be more forgiving. Progress bars are a fairly niche convenience function, so it would be better to let the feature drop out for older versions of pooch (assuming the rest of PyVista's use of `pooch` will work).